# What could be the possible solution to golang ambigious import found package in multiple modules issue?

Tags: go, go-modules, cosmos, cosmos-sdk

In the go.mod file of the project, I encountered an issue with one of the indirect imports. The error message I received states that there is an ambiguous import, indicating that the Go compiler is unsure about the source of the correct package.

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Error message:

```
error while importing cosmossdk.io/tools/rosetta/lib/errors: ambiguous import: found package github.com/coinbase/rosetta-sdk-go/types in multiple modules:
    github.com/coinbase/rosetta-sdk-go v0.4.6 (~/go/pkg/mod/github.com/coinbase/rosetta-sdk-go@v0.4.6/types)
    github.com/coinbase/rosetta-sdk-go/types v1.0.0 (~/go/pkg/mod/github.com/coinbase/rosetta-sdk-go/types@v1.0.0)
```

go.mod file:

```
require (
    cosmossdk.io/api v0.3.1
    cosmossdk.io/errors v1.0.0-beta.7
    cosmossdk.io/math v1.0.0
    github.com/CosmWasm/wasmd v1.0.0
    github.com/avast/retry-go/v4 v4.3.3
    github.com/btcsuite/btcd v0.23.0
    github.com/btcsuite/btcd/btcutil v1.1.2
    github.com/cometbft/cometbft v0.37.1
    github.com/cosmos/cosmos-proto v1.0.0-beta.2
    github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk v0.47.1
    github.com/cosmos/go-bip39 v1.0.0
    github.com/cosmos/gogoproto v1.4.8
    github.com/cosmos/ibc-go/v7 v7.0.0
    github.com/cosmos/ics23/go v0.9.1-0.20221207100636-b1abd8678aab
    github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum v1.11.4
    github.com/gofrs/flock v0.8.1
    github.com/gogo/protobuf v1.3.3
    github.com/google/go-cmp v0.5.9
    github.com/google/go-github/v43 v43.0.0
    github.com/gorilla/websocket v1.5.0
    github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway v1.16.0
    github.com/icon-project/IBC-Integration v0.0.0-20230416064536-48d70570734d
    github.com/icon-project/goloop v1.3.4
    github.com/icon-project/icon-bridge v0.0.11
    github.com/jsternberg/zap-logfmt v1.3.0
    github.com/pkg/errors v0.9.1
    github.com/prometheus/client_golang v1.15.0
    github.com/spf13/cobra v1.7.0
    github.com/spf13/viper v1.15.0
    github.com/stretchr/testify v1.8.2
    github.com/tyler-smith/go-bip39 v1.1.0
    go.uber.org/multierr v1.8.0
    go.uber.org/zap v1.24.0
    golang.org/x/crypto v0.8.0
    golang.org/x/mod v0.10.0
    golang.org/x/sync v0.1.0
    golang.org/x/text v0.9.0
    google.golang.org/grpc v1.54.0
    gopkg.in/yaml.v2 v2.4.0
    gopkg.in/yaml.v3 v3.0.1

)

require (
    cloud.google.com/go v0.110.0 // indirect
    cloud.google.com/go/compute v1.18.0 // indirect
    cloud.google.com/go/compute/metadata v0.2.3 // indirect
    cloud.google.com/go/iam v0.12.0 // indirect
    cloud.google.com/go/storage v1.29.0 // indirect
    cosmossdk.io/core v0.5.1 // indirect
    cosmossdk.io/depinject v1.0.0-alpha.3 // indirect
    cosmossdk.io/tools/rosetta v0.2.1 // indirect
    filippo.io/edwards25519 v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/99designs/go-keychain v0.0.0-20191008050251-8e49817e8af4 // indirect
    github.com/99designs/keyring v1.2.2 // indirect
    github.com/ChainSafe/go-schnorrkel v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/CosmWasm/wasmvm v1.2.3 // indirect
    github.com/armon/go-metrics v0.4.1 // indirect
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go v1.44.203 // indirect
    github.com/benbjohnson/clock v1.3.0 // indirect
    github.com/beorn7/perks v1.0.1 // indirect
    github.com/bgentry/go-netrc v0.0.0-20140422174119-9fd32a8b3d3d // indirect
    github.com/bgentry/speakeasy v0.1.1-0.20220910012023-760eaf8b6816 // indirect
    github.com/bshuster-repo/logrus-logstash-hook v0.4.1 // indirect
    github.com/btcsuite/btcd/btcec/v2 v2.3.2 // indirect
    github.com/btcsuite/btcd/chaincfg/chainhash v1.0.1 // indirect
    github.com/cenkalti/backoff/v4 v4.1.3 // indirect
    github.com/cespare/xxhash v1.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/cespare/xxhash/v2 v2.2.0 // indirect
    github.com/chzyer/readline v1.5.1 // indirect
    github.com/cockroachdb/apd/v2 v2.0.2 // indirect
    github.com/coinbase/rosetta-sdk-go/types v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/cometbft/cometbft-db v0.7.0 // indirect
    github.com/confio/ics23/go v0.9.0 // indirect
    github.com/cosmos/btcutil v1.0.5 // indirect
    github.com/cosmos/gogogateway v1.2.0 // indirect
    github.com/cosmos/iavl v0.20.0 // indirect
    github.com/cosmos/ledger-cosmos-go v0.12.2 // indirect
    github.com/cosmos/rosetta-sdk-go v0.10.0 // indirect
    github.com/creachadair/taskgroup v0.4.2 // indirect
    github.com/danieljoos/wincred v1.1.2 // indirect
    github.com/davecgh/go-spew v1.1.1 // indirect
    github.com/decred/dcrd/dcrec/secp256k1/v4 v4.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/desertbit/timer v0.0.0-20180107155436-c41aec40b27f // indirect
    github.com/dgraph-io/badger/v2 v2.2007.4 // indirect
    github.com/dgraph-io/ristretto v0.1.1 // indirect
    github.com/dgryski/go-farm v0.0.0-20200201041132-a6ae2369ad13 // indirect
    github.com/docker/distribution v2.8.1+incompatible // indirect
    github.com/dustin/go-humanize v1.0.1 // indirect
    github.com/dvsekhvalnov/jose2go v1.5.0 // indirect
    github.com/evalphobia/logrus_fluent v0.5.4 // indirect
    github.com/felixge/httpsnoop v1.0.2 // indirect
    github.com/fluent/fluent-logger-golang v1.4.0 // indirect
    github.com/frankban/quicktest v1.14.4 // indirect
    github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify v1.6.0 // indirect
    github.com/go-kit/kit v0.12.0 // indirect
    github.com/go-kit/log v0.2.1 // indirect
    github.com/go-logfmt/logfmt v0.6.0 // indirect
    github.com/go-stack/stack v1.8.1 // indirect
    github.com/godbus/dbus v0.0.0-20190726142602-4481cbc300e2 // indirect
    github.com/gofrs/uuid v4.3.0+incompatible // indirect
    github.com/gogo/googleapis v1.4.1 // indirect
    github.com/golang/glog v1.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/golang/groupcache v0.0.0-20210331224755-41bb18bfe9da // indirect
    github.com/golang/mock v1.6.0 // indirect
    github.com/golang/protobuf v1.5.3 // indirect
    github.com/golang/snappy v0.0.4 // indirect
    github.com/google/btree v1.1.2 // indirect
    github.com/google/go-querystring v1.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/google/gofuzz v1.2.0 // indirect
    github.com/google/orderedcode v0.0.1 // indirect
    github.com/google/uuid v1.3.0 // indirect
    github.com/googleapis/enterprise-certificate-proxy v0.2.3 // indirect
    github.com/googleapis/gax-go/v2 v2.7.0 // indirect
    github.com/gorilla/handlers v1.5.1 // indirect
    github.com/gorilla/mux v1.8.0 // indirect
    github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware v1.3.0 // indirect
    github.com/gsterjov/go-libsecret v0.0.0-20161001094733-a6f4afe4910c // indirect
    github.com/gtank/merlin v0.1.1 // indirect
    github.com/gtank/ristretto255 v0.1.2 // indirect
    github.com/haltingstate/secp256k1-go v0.0.0-20151224084235-572209b26df6 // indirect
    github.com/hashicorp/go-cleanhttp v0.5.2 // indirect
    github.com/hashicorp/go-getter v1.7.0 // indirect
    github.com/hashicorp/go-immutable-radix v1.3.1 // indirect
    github.com/hashicorp/go-safetemp v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/hashicorp/go-version v1.6.0 // indirect
    github.com/hashicorp/golang-lru v0.5.5-0.20210104140557-80c98217689d // indirect
    github.com/hashicorp/hcl v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/hdevalence/ed25519consensus v0.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/holiman/uint256 v1.2.0 // indirect
    github.com/huandu/skiplist v1.2.0 // indirect
    github.com/improbable-eng/grpc-web v0.15.0 // indirect
    github.com/inconshreveable/mousetrap v1.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/jmespath/go-jmespath v0.4.0 // indirect
    github.com/jmhodges/levigo v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/klauspost/compress v1.16.3 // indirect
    github.com/labstack/echo/v4 v4.9.0 // indirect
    github.com/labstack/gommon v0.3.1 // indirect
    github.com/lib/pq v1.10.7 // indirect
    github.com/libp2p/go-buffer-pool v0.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/magiconair/properties v1.8.7 // indirect
    github.com/manifoldco/promptui v0.9.0 // indirect
    github.com/mattn/go-colorable v0.1.13 // indirect
    github.com/mattn/go-isatty v0.0.18 // indirect
    github.com/matttproud/golang_protobuf_extensions v1.0.4 // indirect
    github.com/mimoo/StrobeGo v0.0.0-20220103164710-9a04d6ca976b // indirect
    github.com/minio/highwayhash v1.0.2 // indirect
    github.com/mitchellh/go-homedir v1.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/mitchellh/go-testing-interface v1.14.1 // indirect
    github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure v1.5.0 // indirect
    github.com/mtibben/percent v0.2.1 // indirect
    github.com/opencontainers/go-digest v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/pelletier/go-toml/v2 v2.0.7 // indirect
    github.com/petermattis/goid v0.0.0-20221215004737-a150e88a970d // indirect
    github.com/philhofer/fwd v1.1.1 // indirect
    github.com/pmezard/go-difflib v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/prometheus/client_model v0.3.0 // indirect
    github.com/prometheus/common v0.42.0 // indirect
    github.com/prometheus/procfs v0.9.0 // indirect
    github.com/rakyll/statik v0.1.7 // indirect
    github.com/rcrowley/go-metrics v0.0.0-20201227073835-cf1acfcdf475 // indirect
    github.com/rivo/uniseg v0.4.4 // indirect
    github.com/rs/cors v1.8.3 // indirect
    github.com/sasha-s/go-deadlock v0.3.1 // indirect
    github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.9.0 // indirect
    github.com/spf13/afero v1.9.3 // indirect
    github.com/spf13/cast v1.5.0 // indirect
    github.com/spf13/jwalterweatherman v1.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/spf13/pflag v1.0.5 // indirect
    github.com/subosito/gotenv v1.4.2 // indirect
    github.com/syndtr/goleveldb v1.0.1-0.20220721030215-126854af5e6d // indirect
    github.com/tecbot/gorocksdb v0.0.0-20191217155057-f0fad39f321c // indirect
    github.com/tendermint/go-amino v0.16.0 // indirect
    github.com/tidwall/btree v1.6.0 // indirect
    github.com/tinylib/msgp v1.1.5 // indirect
    github.com/tklauser/numcpus v0.4.0 // indirect
    github.com/ulikunitz/xz v0.5.11 // indirect
    github.com/valyala/bytebufferpool v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/valyala/fasttemplate v1.2.1 // indirect
    github.com/vmihailenco/msgpack/v4 v4.3.11 // indirect
    github.com/vmihailenco/tagparser v0.1.1 // indirect
    github.com/zondax/hid v0.9.1 // indirect
    github.com/zondax/ledger-go v0.14.1 // indirect
    go.etcd.io/bbolt v1.3.7 // indirect
    go.opencensus.io v0.24.0 // indirect
    go.uber.org/atomic v1.10.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/exp v0.0.0-20230321023759-10a507213a29 // indirect
    golang.org/x/net v0.9.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/oauth2 v0.5.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/sys v0.7.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/term v0.7.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/xerrors v0.0.0-20220907171357-04be3eba64a2 // indirect
    google.golang.org/api v0.110.0 // indirect
    google.golang.org/appengine v1.6.7 // indirect
    google.golang.org/genproto v0.0.0-20230216225411-c8e22ba71e44 // indirect
    google.golang.org/protobuf v1.30.0 // indirect
    gopkg.in/ini.v1 v1.67.0 // indirect
    gopkg.in/natefinch/lumberjack.v2 v2.0.0 // indirect
    nhooyr.io/websocket v1.8.6 // indirect
    pgregory.net/rapid v0.5.5 // indirect
    sigs.k8s.io/yaml v1.3.0 // indirect
)

replace (
    github.com/ChainSafe/go-schnorrkel => github.com/ChainSafe/go-schnorrkel v0.0.0-20200405005733-88cbf1b4c40d
    github.com/CosmWasm/wasmd => github.com/cosmwasm/wasmd v0.40.0-rc.1.0.20230424144037-55647a1fd1f9
    // github.com/CosmWasm/wasmd => github.com/archway-network/archway-wasmd v0.29.2-archway
    github.com/gogo/protobuf => github.com/regen-network/protobuf v1.3.3-alpha.regen.1
    github.com/icon-project/IBC-Integration => github.com/icon-project/ibc-integration v0.0.0-20230619065023-ddc96101b9b1
)
```

Comment: You’ve required two modules which have packages with the same import path. You must fix the requirements and only depend on one of those modules.